# ¿Es Stack Overflow en español un videojuego?

Tags: discusión

Estoy visitando el sitio desde el sábado 18 de marzo y he notado una sobreactividad de usuarios con alto puntaje que le están haciendo a la policía de las preguntas.

Además, en Meta gran parte de las preguntas y comentarios son sobre las puntuaciones: que sin con esto sube el puntaje, que si con lo otro aparece en el home page, que si se publica la pregunta en otra página, que me editaron mi pregunta, que si es un duplicado, ad infinitum.

¿No es Stack Overflow en español un sitio de preguntas sobre programación?

Comment: Creo que no logro entender del todo tu pregunta, talvés con un par de ejemplos quedaría más claro. Por cierto, la respuesta a tu última pregunta es Sí, [es.so] es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas sobre programación.

Comment: ¿Es stackoverflow en español un video juego? No, y no entiendo porque la analogía. Si buscas un debate considero es suficiente con las  preguntas que se tienen actualmente sobre los temas que mencionas.

Comment: La pregunta es retórica, para que cada cual reflexioné su punto de vista

Comment: Creo que @ixi queria dar a entender que muchos usuarios se procupan muchos por su nivel de reputacion y la cantidad de medallas que consiguen, en vez de preocuparse por preguntar o responder correctamente. Bueno eso fue lo que entendi de su cuestionamiento y debo de admitir que a mi me gusta que la comunidad haga este tipo  premios ya que hace visibles a las personas con mas experiencia y asi que sea cuantitativo tu desempeño.

Comment: La gamificación por si misma no es mala mientras no se pierda de vista el objetivo de servir a la comunidad. En los poco días que tengo de visitar la página ya he visto demasiados ejemplos de gente que descalifica preguntas y respuestas sin razón en vez de contestarlas

Comment: Todo stack-exchange es un juego o una cosa seria, depende del observador.. XD

Comment: No es un videojuego, pero si es un juego... _ludificación_ sería el equivalente en español de _gamification_: https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-gamification/

Comment: Afortunadamente es un sitio multicultural, donde usuarios de diferentes países colaboran con preguntas y respuestas, algunos usuarios tienden a ser más *frios* que otros y no hay porque tomarlo personal, todo lo contrario, entre todos nos ayudamos a que crezca esta comunidad. Uno de los principales objetivos es ayudar y cada quien lo hace a su manera, **te propongo a que partamos de ese principio**, todos los usuarios de esta comunidad tienen la necesidad de ayudar o ser ayudados y no hay porque pensar lo contrario. Recuerda que no todos pensamos igual y eso hace la comundad crezca, únicos :)

Comment: Menos mal aquí no pierdes puntos porque sino tendrías hace rato "game over" jaja. Seré fundido a negativos pero "worth it". Que preguntas ve uno aquí xD! jaja

Answer (score -9, accepted):

Este usuario se refiere a lo molesto que es que usuarios que no tienen nada más que hacer tomen el papel de policías y se pasen por todas las preguntas solo para hacer notar si está mal redactada una respuesta.
No es que sea un "videojuego" literalmente, pero sí considero que si continúan con esa actitud van a hacer que la gente se aleje o le de pena comentar.

Comment: Pero es en serio, el juego está incluido en el diseño del sitio.

Comment: Aqui no solo se busca que se resuelvan los problemas. Se buscan preguntas y respuestas de calidad. Y la redaccion es importante, el formato es importante, la adecuacion es importante. Por eso se editan, se mejoran o se cierran preguntas/respuestas. Un saludo

Comment: `...se tomen el papel de policías y se pasen por todas las preguntas solo para hacer notar si está mal redactada una respuesta` = por favor lee **[¿Por qué puede la gente editar mis mensajes? ¿Cómo funciona el trabajo de edición?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/editing) y [revisión](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)**, también puedes dar un vistazo al [Centro de Ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 19):

Stack Overflow en español, así como todos los sitios de Stack Exchange, tienen un modelo basado en la ludificación (*gamification* en inglés). Esto es, se trata de una comunidad en la que en paralelo al problema en sí que quiere resolver se ofrecen unas recompensas (puntos, medallas, privilegios) para incitar a la gente a que se registre y colabore. Al fin y al cabo, es un modelo que se usa últimamente en muchas otras comunidades virtuales. Llámalo videojuego, llámalo *modus operandi*.

Es cierto que a veces este modelo hace que el objetivo final (ayudar) quede algo borroso en la batalla por esos "caramelos", pero por lo general da buenos resultados (mira la [lista de sitios](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic), preguntas, visitantes, respuestas... es escandalosamente exitoso).

No dejes que los árboles te impidan ver el bosque: tú vienes aquí a preguntar y lo que quieres son respuestas. ¿Cómo puedes conseguirlas? Presentando preguntas claras, con ejemplos y mostrando tus esfuerzos. Por tanto, toma los comentarios de los otros como recomendaciones para mejorar. Ya verás como la experiencia cada vez será más agradable.

Comment: Mejor dicho imposible!

Comment: Anda, esta respuesta se aproxima peligrosamente a la medalla reversión.

Comment: Peligrosamente? es la medalla reversión en persona jaja

Answer (score 12):

StackOverflow en Español es un sitio web, no es un videojuego, y tampoco es una página para descargar videojuegos.

Lo que sí es posible, es hacer preguntas que traten sobre cómo programar videojuegos. Si se tiene una base mínima de conocimiento, algún problema con Unity 3D o Unreal Engine, algún código que falla, los usuarios quizás podrán resolverlo.

Si no pueden resolverlo, con la suficiente reputación, se pueden dar recompensas para mayor visibilidad a la pregunta, así la gente le da mayor prioridad para solucionarlo.

Por otra parte, podemos decir que si tiene movimiento es un video. Este sitio no tiene movimiento, a no ser que te vayas moviendo por todo el sitio. Tampoco es un juego, no se debería tomar el sitio a broma, ya que te pueden banear la cuenta. Depende de la seriedad con la que uno se toma el reglamento.

Answer (score 7):

Justo como lo decía en los comentarios, ahora puedo poner una respuesta más completa.

Afortunadamente es un sitio multicultural, donde diferentes usuarios de diferentes países colaboran con preguntas y respuestas, algunos usuarios tienden a ser más frios o directos que otros y no hay porque tomarlo personal, todo lo contrario, entre todos nos ayudamos y al mismo tiempo a que crezca esta comunidad.

Uno de los principales objetivos de Stack Overflow en Español (así como todos los sitios de Stack Exchange) es ayudar y cada quien lo hace a su manera, te propongo a que partamos de ese principio, todos los usuarios de esta comunidad tienen la necesidad de ayudar o ser ayudados y no hay porque pensar lo contrario.

Recuerda que no todos pensamos igual y para lo que algunos puede ser algo grosero, para otros es totalmente lo contrario y lo ven normal, también recuerda que **todo comportamiento tiene una intención positiva**, es decir, aunque la intención de algún otro usuario sea mala hacia contigo siempre existe uno o más motivos por los cuales haya un aprendizaje en todos y cada una de las interacciones que puedas tener dentro de Stack Overflow en Español.

Sigamos ayudándonos entre nosotros dejando a un lado los temas personales, y te aseguro que tu estancia en este sitio será mucho más placentera.

Comment: Exacto. En caso de duda, _presume buena fe_. Lo dicen en Wikipedia y es un lema que sirve mucho para generar buen rollo.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Es Stack Overflow en español un videojuego?

Como ya han mencionados mis otros colegas SOes no es un videojuego pero la base de "recompensas" si es parte de la ludificación. En complemento a lo que comenta @fedorqui en su respuesta, especificamente la afirmación "es escandalosamente exitoso" te comento:

StackOverflow sin puntaje no sería tan divertido! Vamos que es verdad que hay personas que viven por los puntos pero bueno esto se aplica retóricamente a cualquier aspecto de la vida. Los humanos somos por naturaleza competitivos y pienso que un poco de competencia "sana" nunca es mala. Además la competencia genera excelencia, es decir, si ves una buena respuesta y quieres contribuir al OP a solucionar tu pregunta no te gustaría dar una respuesta mejor que la presente? o aunque sea que esté a su altura?

> Estoy visitando el sitio desde el sábado 18 de marzo y he notado una
>   sobreactividad de usuarios con alto puntaje que le están haciendo a la
>   policía de las preguntas.

Agradezcamos que sea así porque sino sería un sitio más al que visitas una vez y no vuelves por presentar fallos en la calidad de su servicio. Estos usuarios con alto puntaje generan más confianza en las respuestas dadas en este sitio. Por qué? Porque sencillamente sabes que no "googlean" la pregunta y confias en que no copian como respuesta el primer texto que vieron y son ellos mismos los que se encargan de que el sitio no desmejore.

Tiene lógica el que exista un sistema de puntuación ya que en cierta forma genera un orden en muchos sentidos. Igual motiva mucho cuando te esfuerzas en redactar una respuesta y la comunidad la valora, sientes que vale la pena el esfuerzo porque al final sólo queda eso las ganas que tengas de colaborar a una comunidad en donde el conocimiento es gratuito.

> Además, en Meta gran parte de las preguntas y comentarios son sobre
>   las puntuaciones: que sin con esto sube el puntaje, que si con lo otro
>   aparece en el home page, que si se publica la pregunta en otra página,
>   que me editaron mi pregunta, que si es un duplicado, ad infinitum.

En resumen, si, los puntos son importantes y siempre escucharás a las personas hablando de ellos. Realicemos algunas analogias:

Si estás en un colegio escuchas a los alumnos hablando más de las materias que están cursando o de sus puntajes?

Si estás en un empleo escuchas más sobre resultados o sobre procedimientos?

Claramente significa mucho para nosotros cualquier tipo de resultado y SOes ha sabido sacar partido a ello, es cómo dice fedorqui, (y concluyo con su frase) es por eso que es escandalosamente exitoso.

> ¿No es Stack Overflow en español un sitio de preguntas sobre
>   programación?

Si, definitivamente lo es y además es el mejor en ello. Ahora te pregunto yo: está prohibido divertirse mientras programas/investigas/aprendes? No está cientificamente demostrado que mientras más te diviertas ejecutando una actividad mayor es el aprendizaje y el rendimiento en la misma?

Un saludo.

Comment: Tarde pero seguro.