# ¿Es adictivo el sitio?

Tags: discusión, stackexchange

[Stack Overflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/) está genial y [Biology Stack Exchange](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) en lo que a mí me interesa mucho más, ¡¡¡¡pero SOes es adictivo!!!!. No puedo dejar de revisarlo al menos tres veces al día, es impresionante el volumen de conocimiento ¡¡¡GRATIS!!! que se genera en este sitio. Reviso las preguntas más destacadas y sus respectivas respuestas, en ocasiones voy a formular una pregunta, reviso primero y me doy cuenta de que ya está publicada y respondida. Eso es genial.

Muy buen trabajo, felicidades.
¿Les pasa a ustedes esto o es adicción mía?

Comment: Si, yo lo miro casi a diario y acabas aprendiendo cosas.

Comment: Si, corre por tu vida. Esto es como el hotel california, puedes entrar cuando quieras pero nunca podrás salir

Comment: Como me reí con tu comentario @Pikoh

Comment: Lo que lo hace adictivo es el conocimiento que genera otro usuario preguntando/respondiendo o tu mismo generando una buena pregunta/respuesta , esto es lo que la mola; sin contar en el chat que tenemos  suramerica , centro america y europa ; y si vienen los demas continentes pues bienvenido a SOEs

Answer (score 10):

Es cierto que muchos usuarios pasen mucho tiempo en la pagina, al punto de acceder todos los días y tratar de contestar todas las preguntas que puedan. La sensación de adicción puede deberse a que Stack Overflow en español, así como todos los sitios de Stack Exchange, tienen un modelo basado en la ludificación ó gamificación; en este sistema se ofrecen recompensas (puntos, medallas, privilegios) para incitar a la gente a que se registre y colabore. Por tanto la pagina tiene intensión de crear cierta afición a la misma entre los usuarios.

Por otro lado si la pagina es adictiva o no depende de la perspectiva de cada uno, para algunos responder y ganar reputación puede ser muy importante, para otros es una pagina donde pueden aprender mucho, como una biblioteca virtual dinámica y también una poderosa herramienta para resolver oportunamente los problemas que un desarrollador pueda tener (si se sabe utilizar correctamente).

De alguna u otra forma, ya sea por la ayuda que brinda la pagina, o por la satisfacción de recibir puntos, medallas y comentarios de agradecimiento, la dependencia a la pagina es evidente en la mayoria de los usuarios.

**Preguntas Relacionadas**

[¿Es Stack Overflow en español un videojuego?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1615/es-stack-overflow-en-espa%C3%B1ol-un-videojuego/1617#1617)

Comment: De hecho hay una medalla de [plata](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/54/enthusiast) y una de [oro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/55/fanatic) por acceder un número de días seguidos

Comment: He intentado ganar la de Oro pero cuando estoy cerca me ocupo más de lo normal y fallo @KacosPro. 100 días continuos no es nada fácil jaja

Comment: @Huskie yo lo logré en SO (en inglés). ¡Vamos, tú puedes!

Comment: Gracias @Barranka xD! Felicidades por tu logro en SO.

Comment: @Huskie, un consejo para ganar la medalla de oro de fanático, puedes entrar desde tu celular, también cuenta, solo abres la pagina y ya.

Comment: "que le hace una pestaña mas al chrome"

Comment: Ah ok. Es verdad no se me había ocurrido! gracias the-breaker

Comment: Sumada a mis 20 pestañas que normalmente tengo abiertas porque todas son "necesarias" cuando programo pues no creo que mucho @aloMalbarez jaja

Answer (score 1):

> adicción
>   nombre femenino
>       1. Hábito de conductas peligrosas o de consumo de determinados productos, en especial drogas, y del que no se puede prescindir o
>   resulta muy difícil hacerlo por razones de dependencia psicológica o
>   incluso fisiológica.

- SO no es peligroso.
- Se puede prescindir de SO. Sí, ya hacía mi trabajo sin SO antes de que existiese y sigo siendo capaz de hacerlo.
- No genera dependencia psicológica o fisiológica. En vacaciones acostumbro a no visitar SO, hago un uso mucho menor de Internet y un mayor uso de la playa. Sin sufrir de síndrome de abstinencia.

Sí, es un sitio apasionante. Adictivo no.

> 2. Afición desmesurada a algo.

Desmesurado sigue siendo negativo. Habrá quien tenga una afición desmesurada. Un síntoma de esto es el esforzarse en obtener artificialmente medallas o puntos. Esto lleva, por ejemplo, a hacer ediciones insignificantes o a escribir una gran cantidad de respuestas superficiales.

Comment: Espera, la segunda definición de _adicción_ dice _"Afición desmesurada a algo."_, esa es la definición que aplica en este contexto.

Comment: SOes en sí no es peligroso. La ludificación en sí, como cualquier otro sistema de modificación conductual basado en acción - recompensa, sí lo es. Prueba de ello son, como bien dices, las ediciones y respuestas rápidas y superficiales para ganar reputación rápidamente.

Comment: Tenias que explicar esto _"No genera dependencia psicológica o fisiológica. En vacaciones acostumbro a no visitar SO, hago un uso mucho menor de Internet y un mayor uso de la playa. Sin sufrir de síndrome de abstinencia."_ menos mal que no no hay un StackOverBeaches por que te expulsan!!